# Quick-load JQuery Navigation Menus in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, navigation

Is it possible to replace Wordpress' default menus with a customized navigation menu that doesn't require the page to reload every time a tab is clicked? I know jquery-based navigation menus are easy to build, but I'm wondering how it'll fit into Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax loading of content has very little to do with menus and everything to do with the div that you want to load via Ajax. Take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajaxd-wordpress/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-page-loader-15/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-for-all/ or tabs: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/put/